# g_hash_table_insert malloc(): memory corruption

Tags: c, glib, memory-corruption

I would try to store many lists (arrays) in a Glib hash. Here is the sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <glib.h>

#define NR 10

typedef unsigned char carr[NR];

GHashTable* hasht;
int init = 0;


int main() {

    carr *c, *d;
    int i;

    hasht = g_hash_table_new(g_str_hash, g_str_equal);
    c = g_malloc0(sizeof *c);

    for(i=0; i<NR; i++) {
    *c[i] = 70+i;
    }

    for(i=0; i<NR; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", *c[i]);
    }

    g_hash_table_insert(hasht, "1", c);

    printf("----------------\n");
    d = g_hash_table_lookup(hasht, "1");
    for(i=0; i<NR; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", *d[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can compile this code with this way:

```
gcc -Wall -o arrtest arrtest.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0`
```

If I run the compiled code, I got this error:

```
*** Error in `./arrtest': malloc(): memory corruption: 0x00000000018efe70 ***
```

But if I change the order of two lines above:

```
hasht = g_hash_table_new(g_str_hash, g_str_equal);
c = g_malloc0(sizeof *c);
```

to this:

```
c = g_malloc0(sizeof *c);
hasht = g_hash_table_new(g_str_hash, g_str_equal);
```

the code runs without any problems.

Why?

The project would be to store many lists as this:

```
a = {0, 1, 3, 4, 2, 0, 5, 9, 20};
```

and every list has a string key. The function should be like this:

```
store_in_hash(char * key, int idx)
```

which called from another places. The function checks if the global hash table exists, if not, creates it. Then looks up the key, if doesn't exist, creates a new one, and increments the idx'th item of list. What's the expected way to store many lists in a hash table?

Thank you for your help:

airween

Comment: Have you tried using valgrind?

Comment: I've never ever used valgrind :). First, I would solve this without it, but I'll see that - thanks.

Comment: btw, `*c[i] = 70+i;` (and similar code) is not doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: Well, if I change the 'unsigned char' to simple 'int', then it works... WHY??? :)

Comment: Ok, and what's wrong with that? In this case, the *c[i] is an unsigned char, that would be [0..255], or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is operator precedence:

```
*c[i] = 70+i;
```

The array indexing happens before the pointer dereference. So you want `(*c)[i]` instead. BTW, I'd avoid this confusing code style; your typedef is not necessary, just use char pointers and you won't get into this weird situation.

Comment: Thanks, that works :)

Now I'm going to find, what's the different :)

Anyway, I know, the typedef isn't necessary, I could use the char[NR] anywhere. But I'm afraid with the char pointers should be more confusing... 

Thanks again!

Comment: `*c[0]` works; but `*c[1]` means "dereference the address at c + sizeof(*c)", so you're trying to read past the malloc'd memory block.